# Rails Routing new association path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have households and I have tokens -- Households own tokens

I have an index with households and to create a new token for the household I use:

```
 = link_to 'Issue', new_household_token_path, class: 'btn'
```

Rake routes shows:

```
 new_household_token GET  /households/:household_id/tokens/new(.:format)     tokens#new
```

But I get:

```
 No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"tokens"}
```

But it looks like I do have that route

The Tokens controller has:

```
def new
    @token = Token.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @token }
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `:household_id`. By looking at the route you can see the `household_id` must be included `/households/:household_id/tokens/new(.:format)` in order to hit your `TokensController#new`. Pass your `household_id` to your route, something like (as long as `@household` is not `nil`:

```
= link_to 'Issue', new_household_token_path(@household.id), class: 'btn'
```

Comment: Thanks - just what I needed